# How to use Max and Group By in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to use this line:

```
return  ObjectContext.TH_Proposal.GroupBy.where(/* condition*/).(y => y.ProposalID).Max(y =>y.ProposalDate);
```

I want a result like this using LINQ

```
select * 
from TH_Proposal
where ProposalDate in (select max(ProposalDate)from TH_Proposal group by  ProposalID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
ObjectContext.TH_Proposal.GroupBy(
                  p => p.ProposalID,
                  (id, g) => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProposalDate).First());
```

This groups the entries by `ProposalID` and selects the one with the highest `ProposalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier in Linq than SQL since Linq can take the first item of each group:

```
return  
    ObjectContext.TH_Proposal
                 .OrderBy(y => y.ProposalDate)
                 .GroupBy(y => y.ProposalID)
                 .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: I guess this may perform faster than my solution (ordering all at once), but I'm never sure if `GroupBy` keeps the order of elements...may depend on the dbms/query provider etc...

Comment: @RenéVogt Good point.  I know order is preserved in Linq-to-objects, not certain if it is in Linq-to-entities.